# Make an animation faster?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that moves two obstacles faster every few seconds.

Here is the code:

```
blockmovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.005 target:self selector:@selector(blockermoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Here is the code for the `blockermoving`:

```
blockerleft.center = CGPointMake(blockerleft.center.x, blockerleft.center.y - 1);

blockerright.center = CGPointMake(blockerright.center.x, blockerright.center.y - 1);
```

**The problem is that I do not know how to make it 'faster' every few seconds. How can I accelerate the movement?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at CoreAnimation - especially CAShapeLayer.

Comment: I highly recommend that you look into an animation tutorial, for instance: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes

Comment: What do you mean by "faster" ? Do you want the speed of the movement to increase after each animation or do you only want a "faster" continuous movement ?

Comment: Depending on your needs, UIView animations, Core Animation, UIKit Dynamics, and Sprite Kit might be good topics to look at. (The acceleration makes it sound like you might want a sort of physics simulation, which would be either one of the last two).

Comment: tYp, i wanted to to increase after each animation